# RegEx to match alphanumeric number of certain length starting with a number

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement for regex - starting with a number and then can have letter numbers and special characters `-_.\\s+` for hyphen, dot, underscore and space, etc. My other important requirement is that the length of the number is to be between 5 and 30 (inclusive) BUT it should not be 10 or 12 characters in length. I have prepared a regex as below:

```
^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_.\\\s+]{5,30}$
```

I understand that the above regex regulates length between 5 and 30 characters BUT how do I restrict it NOT to have 10 or 12 characters length.

Please help.

Comment: What necessitates these requirements? What inputs are you working on?

Comment: Please add examples of valid and invalid input.

Comment: Notice that your regex will scan a number between 6 & 31 characters, not 5 & 30.  That initial digit is an extra character. Is that what you meant?

Comment: You really should consider to _not_ check each and every requirement with a regular expression. For the pattern requirement, a regular expresseion seems to be a good fit. But for the length ... why not simply check the input string and/or the number in it? No need to complicate things ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> BUT how do I restrict it NOT to have 10 or 12 characters length.

You could insert a negative lookahead at the start of the pattern to not expect 10 or 12 characters: `(?!.{10}$|.{12}$)`.

The whole pattern would then be:

```
^(?!.{10}$|.{12}$)[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_.\\\s+]{5,30}$
```

Answer (score 0):

As the pattern should start with a digit, you might do that first and then add to negative lookaheads to prevent the lookaheads to fire when the string does not start with a digit.

If you don't want to match newlines, using Java you can change `\s` to `\h` to match horizontal whitespace characters.

```
^[0-9](?!.{9}$|.{11}$)[a-zA-Z0-9-_.\\\h+]{4,29}$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZzQYrN/1).

A longer version without using lookaheads, but making use of a greedy quantifier and optional [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

The pattern matches either 5-9 chars, 11 chars or 13-30 chars.

```
^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-_.\\h+]{4,8}+(?>[a-zA-Z0-9-_.\\h+]{2}(?>[a-zA-Z0-9-_.\\h+]{2,19})?)?$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdAtXg/1).

Answer (score -1):

```
^(?!.*\b\d{10}\b)(?!.*\b\d{12}\b)[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-_.\\s+]{4,29}$
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but probably add an explanation of what you did and why. Code-only answers are discouraged because using it i  hit or miss if you don't understand the code.